# How to prevent invalid column error in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, ssms, sqldatatypes

I have two tables in the trading schema -

```
trading.members (
  "member_id" VARCHAR(6),
  "first_name" VARCHAR(7),
  "region" VARCHAR(13)
);

trading.transactions (
  "txn_id" INTEGER,
  "member_id" VARCHAR(6),
  "ticker" VARCHAR(3),
  "txn_date" DATE,
  "txn_type" VARCHAR(4),
  "quantity" FLOAT,
  "percentage_fee" FLOAT,
  "txn_time" TIMESTAMP)
```

The task is to create a temp table that has each mentor's name, region and end of year total quantity for each ticker. This table will be used for further analysis.

Current query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp_table;

CREATE TABLE #temp_table
(
    "first_name" varchar(50),
    "region" varchar(50),
    "ticker" varchar(5),
    "year_end" date,
    "yearly_quantity" float
);  

WITH cte_combined_data AS
(
    SELECT 
        mem.first_name AS first_name,
        mem.region AS region,
        trans.ticker AS ticker,
        trans.txn_date AS t_date,
        CASE 
            WHEN trans.txn_type = 'BUY' THEN trans.quantity
            WHEN trans.txn_type = 'SELL' THEN -trans.quantity
        END AS total_quantity
    FROM 
        trading.members mem
    LEFT JOIN 
        trading.transactions trans ON mem.member_id = trans.member_id
    WHERE 
        trans.txn_date <='2020-12-31' 
)
INSERT INTO #temp_table 
SELECT
    first_name, 
    region,
    ticker,
    LEFT(CAST(t_date AS CHAR), 4) AS year_end,
    SUM(total_quantity) AS yearly_quantity
FROM  
    cte_combined_data
GROUP BY 
    first_name, region, ticker, year_end
```

I get this error when I run the current query:

> Invalid column name 'year_end'

error snapshot: [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAqCq.png)

Do you know how can I solve this error? I have been stuck on this for a while now so any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

1. Tried replacing LEFT() with DATETRUNC() and got same error
2. Restarted SSMS multiple times but it didnt help.

Comment: I have changed the tags since this is a sql-server/MSsql problem not MYSQL.

Comment: The GROUP BY clause is evaluated _before_ the SELECT list, so the year_end column alias hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use same String function in the GROUP BY, Alias name not allowed in GROUP BY

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp_table;
CREATE TABLE #temp_table
("first_name" varchar(50)
,"region" varchar(50)
,"ticker" varchar(5)
,"year_end" date
,"yearly_quantity" float);  

WITH cte_combined_data as (
  SELECT mem.first_name as first_name
 ,mem.region as region
 ,trans.ticker as ticker
 ,trans.txn_date as t_date
  ,CASE WHEN trans.txn_type = 'BUY' THEN trans.quantity
      WHEN trans.txn_type = 'SELL' THEN -trans.quantity
      END as total_quantity
FROM trading.members mem
LEFT JOIN trading.transactions trans
ON mem.member_id = trans.member_id
WHERE trans.txn_date <='2020-12-31' 
 )

INSERT INTO #temp_table 

SELECT first_name
,region
,ticker
,LEFT(CAST(t_date as CHAR) ,4) as year_end
,SUM(total_quantity) as yearly_quantity

FROM  cte_combined_data
GROUP BY first_name
,region
,ticker
,LEFT(CAST(t_date as CHAR) ,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

use below script -- pass the expression if you want to do group by rather than the alias

```
SELECT first_name
,region
,ticker
,LEFT(CAST(t_date as CHAR) ,4) as year_end
,SUM(total_quantity) as yearly_quantity

FROM  cte_combined_data
GROUP BY first_name
,region
,ticker
,LEFT(CAST(t_date as CHAR) ,4)
```